# How to enable collisions when using a Pallet Rack object and forklifts as resources

Tags: anylogic

I am using paths to define where my forklifts can move. I understand that there are two ways of defining my forklifts that are to be used for transferring the agents from their home location to the rack system. I wanted to know how I can set up the system so that it takes collisions into account, or otherwise, slow down when there is another forklift in front.

If I use the resource method, collisions do not apply. If I use the move by transport method, I can’t pick the pallet rack as my destination since it’s limited to conveyors, xyz positions and other types not including a pallet rack.

Can someone please let me know what is the correct way for solving this ?

Comment: use transporters from the material handling library to avoid collisions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to mix and match: Use transporters from the MH library for the actual transport. Make them move to the entry of your alley (or find a point close to the actual storing position, only possible with coding).

Once at that position, "hand over" the item to a Resource-Pool agent to store within your pallet rack. Or completely ignore using resources for storing into pallet racks and apply some delay only, once the transporter arrived at that position

Comment: Thanks Benjamin, can you please suggest how I can handover the item to the resource pool ? The confusion is how I can define the Agent location within the RackStore block, since now the agent (pallet) will be in the hands of the transport and no longer in the receivingDock node. Here is an image of the model: https://i.ibb.co/r7SMKby/Screen-Shot-2021-03-14-at-12-15-33-PM.png

Comment: please open a new question for this, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask :)